# How to fix Right-click issue in WebStorm on Mac

Tags: macos, multi-touch, mouse, third-party, bettertouchtool

I am using the BetterTouchTool Version 1.47, and configured that a right click should be simulated using a tap with two fingers using the magic mouse (see picture). [image: BetterTouchTool Configuration]

The problem is that WebStorm 11.0.3 does not register the event, hence I am not able to right click in WebStorm using the magic mouse. I am running OS X El Capitan 10.11.1. Has anyone experienced the same thing, or have a solution to the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I got the 1.5 update of BetterTouchTool, and upgraded WebStorm to 11.0.3 the problem vanished.